# Right way to normalize multiple input and output data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I want to predict temperature with a LSTM using the following inputs:

> Temperature,
>   Pressure,
>   Windspeed

My output is:

> Temperature

What is the best way to normalize the input data?
Should i just min max scale all of the 3 inputs together? Which would then also mean that the normalized output differs as min and max from Temperature are not in same range as Windspeed and Pressure.

Or should i min max normalize all the inputs separately?

Answer (score 0):

Each input separately to zero-mean, unit-norm and same for the output.
The effects of normalization and its importance are argued in section 4.3 of the now-famous [Efficient Backpropagation](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You should do all separately, this is important because the range or distribution of one variable can minimize the gradient for another if it's much larger.

I would also recommend using sklearn for this since it allows you to convert train, test, and validate sets using the same parameters.

A working example was provided in this answer.

[Keras: Using Predict with a Model Trained with Normalized Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49696981/keras-using-predict-with-a-model-trained-with-normalized-data/49699947#49699947)